# OSX - Open two multiple windows of same program in different spaces on startup?

Tags: macos, boot, osx-spaces

When OSX starts up, I'd like to have two Google Chrome windows open in two different spaces, two terminal windows in different spaces, etc. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Applescript would probably be your best solution. I don't have the time now to write the script for you but these links will help you learn the basics (it's pretty easy to pick up for what you need). Also open the Applescript Editor on your Mac then go to Help > Applescript Help. There are links within the help that open Apple's online Applescript Language Guide to expand on what you learned at macosxautomation.com.
Also, a good book to learn from is

**MacOSXAutomation**: http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/learn.html

**AppleScript 1-2-3**: [http://www.amazon.com/Apple-Training-AppleScript-Sal-Soghoian/dp/0321149319/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1290187236&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321149319)

**Applescript Language Guide**: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html